# translucent navigation bar iPhone5 xcode5

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios7, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5 to build an app for ios7.  I have set the navigation bar in the storyboard to default style translucent checked and tint color to clear.  On my iPhone 4 the navigation bar is totally clear with the title and buttons showing up just as words.  I love it.  However on the iPhone 5 the navigation bar is a translucent white,  which I'm not too wild about.  Does anyone know why the difference between the two phones and is there anyway to make the iPhone 5 have a totally clear navigation bar?

Comment: iOS 7 is CURRENTLY UNDER NDA. Questions should be directed to Apple's own Developer Forums. https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios

Comment: This is no longer under NDA and I have this problem too. It seems that the solution is to make iPhone4 and iPhone4S have solid backgrounds, but I do not know the best way to detect which device supports translucency and which do not.